# Unexpected output in Python while executing simple loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this rather simple loop

```
cities = ['Merano', 'Madrid', 'New York', 'Bangkok']
countries = ['Italy', 'Spain', 'USA']

for index, city in enumerate(cities):
    print('This is index:', index)
    print('This is city:', city)
    print('The length of the list \'cities\' is: ', len(cities))
    print(print('The length of the list \'countries\' is: ', len(countries)))
    print(countries[index])
    print(5 * '#')
```

I expect it to break. However, what I did not expect is this output.

```
This is index: 0
This is city: Merano
The length of the list 'cities' is:  4
The length of the list 'countries' is:  3
None
Italy
#####
This is index: 1
This is city: Madrid
The length of the list 'cities' is:  4
The length of the list 'countries' is:  3
None
Spain
....
```

Where is the `none` coming from? I do not `print` this, nor do I execute something where I'd expect this to be printed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(print('The length of the list \'countries\' is: ', len(countries)))
```

in the above line you are printing print functions output.

If you look at function Def it doesn't have a return type so you are getting `None` from the inner `print()` statement.

**Also a remark**-
fix the `index` check for `index > len(countries)`

Answer (score 4):

you used print(print()) in    `print(print('The length of the list \'countries\' is: ', len(countries)))`
use

```
print('The length of the list \'countries\' is: ', len(countries))`
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have 2 print commands

```
print(print('The length of the list \'countries\' is: ', len(countries)))
```

Comment: Oh wow... I should have looked closer ;) Thanks!